# jna load library

Tags: java, dll, load, jna

i'm having a problem on loading a dll with jna. While i can debug the code within eclipse, i get an Exception when i export and run it as a jar file:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unable to load library 'SiUSBXp'

Any ideas why it does not find my dll when i run it as a jar-file?

Thanks!!!!

```
public interface SiUSBXp extends StdCallLibrary {
    byte SI_GetNumDevices(IntByReference numdevices);
    byte SI_GetProductString( int deviceNum, byte[] productString, int options );
    byte SI_Open(IntByReference numdevices);
}

static SiUSBXp INSTANCE;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path","SiUSBXp.dll");
    HashMap<String, StdCallFunctionMapper> optionMap = new HashMap<String, StdCallFunctionMapper>();
    StdCallFunctionMapper myMapper = new StdCallFunctionMapper();
    optionMap.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, myMapper);
    INSTANCE = (SiUSBXp) Native.loadLibrary("SiUSBXp", SiUSBXp.class, optionMap);
}
```

------------------ EDIT ----------------------

The dll is located in the same folder as the jar is

------------------ EDIT 2 ---------------------

I've just tried to run it within windows xp and it works .. but it does not within windows 7 (64 bit)

------------------ EDIT 3 ---------------------
I've solved the problem ... It was due to the java versions installed ... I removed them all, and then only installed the x86 version of java ... after that it worked perfectly

Comment: where is SiUSBXp.dll when you run from jar?

Answer (score 5):

Put the DLL into the "Current Folder" or system variable PATH, or use `-Djna.library.path=(path to the dll)` as VM switch instead of hard-coding.

Comment: Note that jna.library.path is searched in the same manner as PATH; do not include the DLL name in the paths listed in either.

You can set jna.library.path in your code as long as you do it before attempting to load your native library.

Comment: Anything else to try if this doesn't work?  I'm in the same boat and setting the JNA path doesn't help.

Comment: On windows, JNA first searches for DLLs on jna.library.path, the falls back to the system, which searches PATH.

Sometimes a DLL will fail to load because the DLLs on which it depends are not on either path, use "depends.exe" to trace those dependencies.

Comment: Also, if your .so file calls any other library, you need to set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to specify the dir where they are found.
Then also your .so file must be built with 
"g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libexample.so example.cpp -Wl,-rpath=. -L. -lfoo",
where foo is the dependent sharable object library. Specify all libraries called by example.cpp .